# Unity3D C#. Пропорциональное изменение двух переменных

Tags: c#

Есть две переменные:
A = от 0 до 1
B = от 1000 до 10000
Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении одной переменной, пропорционально изменялась в реальном времени и вторая?
То есть при A = 0, B = 1000. При A = 0.5, B = 5000 и так далее.

Нужно однострочное решение с помощью какой-нибудь функции, если таковая имеется

Comment: Вы серьёзно? Это математика 4 класс.. Проценты.

Comment: Мне нужно именно оптимизированное решение, в одну строку. Может есть функция какая-то, по типу Mathf.Пропорционизировать(переменная A, переменная B);

Comment: *"Мне нужно "* --- вы для начала напишите это на листочке бумаге. Потом под это написанное подберите функци из документации.

Comment: Если бы все было так просто, я бы здесь не спрашивал...

Comment: А в чём сложность? Пока кажется на то, что подумать вы не хотите

Comment: Если внимательно посмотреть, тут даже расчёт процентов не нужен. Тут достаточно операции умножения и один if в исключительной ситуации когда A = 0; Всё....

Comment: `при A = 0, B = 1000. При A = 0.5, B = 5000 и так далее.` это не пропорция, пропорции линейные, а у вас при A выросшем на половину, В растет только на 4000, а должно на 4500.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам надо, чтобы при изменениий А, менялось В и наоборот, то, возможно, у вас не 2 переменные, а одна структура данных.

Пример

```
public class MyClass
{
    public double A
    {
        get => _holder;
        set =>_holder = value;      
    }
    
    public double B 
    {
        get => 1000 + (9000 * _holder);
        set => _holder = (value - 1000) / 9000;
    }
    
    private double _holder = 0;
}
```

Проверка

```
var test = new MyClass();
test.A = 0;
Console.WriteLine($"A:{test.A}, B:{test.B}");
test.A = 0.5;
Console.WriteLine($"A:{test.A}, B:{test.B}");
test.A = 1;
Console.WriteLine($"A:{test.A}, B:{test.B}");
test.B = 5000;
Console.WriteLine($"A:{test.A}, B:{test.B}");
```

Вывод

```
A:0, B:1000
A:0.5, B:5500
A:1, B:10000
A:0.444444444444444, B:5000
```

И да, как видите, ваше условие `при A = 0, B = 1000. При A = 0.5, B = 5000 и так далее.` не является пропорцией.

Comment: к сожалению в геймдеве метод "get" "set" использовать противопоказано, особенно в апдейте. процессор спасибо не скажет...

Comment: Это обычные методы, которые мало чем отличаются от любых других методов. Методами же можно в геймдеве пользоваться?

Comment: @SlamphOne кто вам такую ерунду про get set сказал?